# How to upgrade firmware on old HP JetDirect server?

Tags: network-printer, firmware, hp-laserjet

I have a [HP LaserJet 2100tn](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-2100-printer-series/25469) network printer which contains an embedded JetDirect J3111A LAN printing server.

I am trying to update the firmware from version G.05.35 to the latest, which is G.08.49.

However, neither of the methods mentioned on the [firmware download website](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03754288) seem to work:

- the “HP Download Manager” application is outdated and does not work on Windows 7+
- the printer does not even respond to connections on the FTP port
- the HTTP server just serves a page stating “503 Service Not Avaiable” [sic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older versions of the firmware only support upgrading using the [Trival File Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol), but documentation regarding this seems to have been removed from the HP website (This also seems to be the method that HP Download Manager used).

You need to set up a TFTP server on your computer on the default port (69) that will be accessible to the printer. You can for example use [this software](https://github.com/vcabbage/trivialt) available for all popular OS's, or [this python script](https://github.com/brjsp/tftp) written by yours truly.

Then telnet into the printer and type the following commands (assuming that the TFTP server's IP address is `192.0.2.1` and it serves the firmware under the name `example.dld`):

```
tftp-server:192.0.2.1
upgrade-file:example.dld
upgrade
```

Wait about two minutes and do not reboot the printer or the TFTP server during that time. When you can telnet into the printer again, the upgrade should have been successful.

Comment: this worked for my Jetdirect 600N J3113A using Termius and Transfer on a M1 Mac.

Answer (score 1):

For HP Jetdirect devices with firmware versions x.22.xx or later, FTP can be used to upgrade the firmware.
If the HP Jetdirect device has firmware version x.24.xx or greater, Embedded Web Server (EWS) can also be used to upgrade the firmware.

For my 610n (J4169A) at FW version L.21.11 neither FTP, nor EWS nor Telnet update worked.
Finally I got the update running via the HP Web Jetadmin software.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, a 610N with L.21.11. Following this answer, I installed Web JetAdmin, but I still wasn't able to upgrade to the latest L.25.57. Can you provide more details about what you did? Did you use an intermediate firmware to get to a later version?

Comment: For posterity: some 610n's have non-upgradeable firmware, see https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2134146-hp-jetdirect-firmware-archive?page=1#entry-7725460. I'm assuming that's the problem I have, so it looks like I'm SOL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add my recent experience of trying to update the firmware on a J8007G JetDirect server on an HP 690N card (in a LaserJet 5200 with Macs on Big Sur).

The current HP Utility app has an option for Uploading Firmware in its Advanced Options (which are enabled from the View menu).

[image]

However, this just sent the firmware data to the print queue, spooling out loads of paper.

There is no Mac version of the HP Web JetAdmin software, from what I can see.

The EWS manual says to use `ftp`, which (along with `telnet`) has been removed from MacOS 'for security', of course, but I was able to copy over the binaries from an earlier OS version. Unfortunately, that too caused the printer to 'print' the firmware file.

The TFTP server software in the link in kinokijuf's answer seems to have been abandoned, and there's no Mac 64-bit binary release.

However, I'd overlooked that the web front end itself did have an option for uploading firmware.

[image]

Of course, Safari complained about the https certificate having expired in 2014, and it also kept claiming that the web server was timing out when it tried to process the update.

Eventually, I switched to the Vivaldi browser, which worked perfectly, and let me update from 38.04 to V.41.16.

Comment: “The TFTP server software in the link in kinokijuf's answer seems to have been abandoned, and there's no Mac 64-bit binary release.” Does Mac 64-bit support Python3? You have reminded me i had code for a TFTP server lying around, you can check if it works for you.

Comment: @kinokijuf There is a built-in version of python3, and you can of course install any version of python yourself. Thanks, I'll have a look at your script.